# micromedia flash error 1120, 1180

Tags: flash, adobe, m

please can you help me solve this ... thanks

Scene 1, Layer 'Action Layer', Frame 1, Line 1, Column 1    1120: Access of undefined property url.
Scene 1, Layer 'Action Layer', Frame 1, Line 2, Column 1    1180: Call to a possibly undefined method loadVariablesNum.
Scene 1, Layer 'Action Layer', Frame 1, Line 2, Column 18   1120: Access of undefined property url.
Scene 1, Layer 'Action Layer', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 1    1120: Access of undefined property _root.
Scene 1, Layer 'Action Layer', Frame 243, Line 1, Column 19 1120: Access of undefined property _root.

```
url = "xxx";
loadVariablesNum(url + "_main.html", 0);
_root.link = 1;
stop ();
```

and also here

```
pages.gotoAndStop(_root.link);
```

Comment: this is a AS1 it needs to be converted to AS3 ... I tried to read about it but it seems that loadVariablesNum is not usable in AS3... but what to use instead and why the movie loops ?!

Comment: You need to use the URLLoader to load external content: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3externaltext/ The movie might loop when you get any errors (like you do)